# How can I improve my filter of two lists?

Tags: c#, linq

There is probably a better way to make this run faster with big chunks of data but I couldn't find the answer.

```
var myList = realm.All<Equipment>().ToList();
List<Equipment> myList2 = (List<Equipment>)(object)ts;
return (IList<T>)myList2.Where(x => !myList.Any(l => x.id == l.id)).ToList();
```

My main goal is to find the difference between the two lists.

Comment: Why do you cast it as an object first ?

Comment: You could probably use the "Except" operator in Linq. If you provide the comparer (to check on the ID) it will be easier I think.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-find-the-set-difference-between-two-lists-linq

Comment: `Except` doesn't work for classes at least for me it just return the collection

Comment: I will post an example :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Except operator, here is a small example to use the same of "Id" comparison:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    protected bool Equals(Product other)
    {
        return Id == other.Id;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((Product) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id;
    }
}
```

(Not sure this is a correct hashcode but it has been generated so...)

By overriding the Equals/GetHashCode you ensure the reference is not used in the comparison, only the value of the Id.
Then :

```
    var products1 = new List<Product>()
    {
        new Product() {Id = 1},
        new Product() {Id = 2},
        new Product() {Id = 3},
    };

    var products2 = new List<Product>()
    {
        new Product() {Id = 2},
        new Product() {Id = 3},
        new Product() {Id = 4},
    };

    var temp = products1.Except(products2);
```

temp will only contains the product with ID 1.
If you wanted the product with ID 4 you just need to invert products1 and products2.

Small edit : If you cannot touch the original class (in this case "Product") you can also implement a comparer with the IEqualityComparer interface

Comment: And if my ID is a string?

Comment: Exactly the same "Id == other.Id" can be applied to strings too.

Comment: but the return type of GetHashCode() is int

Comment: This is the code generated for an hashcode with a string property : (Id != null ? Id.GetHashCode() : 0);

Comment: Thank you very much!